# How do you describe someone who is in a middle scale often?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, descriptive-grammar

How do you describe someone who is always in the middle? For example, One person is always angry and another really calm and this person is both at times. Or they are shy and outgoing. Like science and art. Basically, they don't fit in a description cause they're always in the middle cause they do both or are both. 
Does this make sense?

Comment: I think that you need to be more specific. You are asking us to cover all the bases.

Comment: They are not extreme in any sense (though you couldn't really use the term 'a moderate' here).

Comment: You're confusing us.  Do you mean someone who vacillates between extremes, or someone who is generally positioned in the middle, between extremes?

Comment: Someone generally between extremes.

Comment: *Middle of the road*, perhaps. It depends on the context.

Comment: Your sentences contradict each other. Is the person *always in the middle* or *both at times.* Anyways this sounds generally like being ***human.***

Comment: Related: [What is a term to refer to two ideas in exact opposition (e.g. good & bad, positive & negative)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329278/what-is-a-term-to-refer-to-two-ideas-in-exact-opposition-e-g-good-bad-posit). Specifically, a now deleted comment on that question: "How about '[bi]polar'?"

Comment: @Mazura That would connote some sort of combination of two extremes, the OP want "*Someone generally between extremes*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any word for a person who moves frequently between two extremes in everything](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216838/is-there-any-word-for-a-person-who-moves-frequently-between-two-extremes-in-ever). The same two comments again: "A normal person." - "Bipolar disorder?"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, that person is ***balanced***.

ODO:

> **[balanced](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/balanced)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> 1.3 (of a person or state of mind) having no emotion too strong or too weak; stable.
>
> ‘a balanced personality’

Answer (score 1):

You could also use **middle-of-the-road** [(Collins defintion)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/middle-of-the-road):

> adjective
>
> 1. not extreme, esp in political views; moderate

Or **level-headed** [(Collins definition)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/level-headed):

> adjective
>
> 1. even-tempered, balanced, and reliable; steady

If you want to emphasize the fact that "they don't fit a description" as you put it, you could also consider **unremarkable**, although that's not exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This was historically seen as a desirable characteristic, the idea that everything in moderation would be good. As such, it was referred to as the **golden mean**.

> The desirable middle between two extremes, one of excess and the other of deficiency.
>   For example, in the Aristotelian view, courage is a virtue, but if taken to excess would manifest as recklessness, and, in deficiency, cowardice.